# What is the TangoMortician?

Tags: google-project-tango

At this point in testing, I've got a slot of data flowing into transmission queues (and then being thrown away :-)  This means I'm taking every image, pointcloud, and pose with C API callbacks.  I don't use the java tango api, and the java app is holding about 48MB of data on average and is configured for a large heap.

For some reason, I keep getting into a situation where I get a log message from the tango_client_api -

> virtual void TangoMortician::binderDied(const
>   android::wp&): Internal Error: TangoService died.

Following this, oddly enough I get a successful connect to the tango service, but everything's pretty much borked.

The only cure I have found is to reboot the tablet, but whatever my app is doing to annoy it causes the issue to return after a handful of debug cycles.

Comment: Did you find the reason of the problem? I have the same situation, but I don't know what is causing it. And how to solve it.

Comment: Not exactly, but it did seem that taking too long in callback processing could cause tango internal issues - I got the impression the mortician was a post crash event handler